# How can I add an object to another object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript variables.  One contains a content object and the other an array of content objects. 
If the contents object already has contents then I can do a push and add to it. I have this working okay in the first part of my if statement.

However if the contents object is null then the push does not work.  How can I make it so that I can add just one content to the null contents object. In other words how can I create a contents object and assign self.content to it in the same time.  I have tried here but it is not working:

```
            if (self.contents) {
                self.contents.push(self.content);
            } else {
                self.contents = [self.content]
            }
```

Comment: It's not javascript.

Comment: Check my answer, if its not working for you you've misspelled something, or are not describing the case properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (self.contents) {
    self.contents.push(self.content);
} else {
    self.contents = [self.content];
}
```